# How can I split my data frame into multiple tables and put them into e list?

Tags: r

I have a data frame with data from two raters to test the reliability of 4 different tests:

```
test1_rater1<-c(1,4,3,2,3,4,1,2,2,3)
test2_rater1<-c(1,3,3,3,2,3,1,1,2,1)
test3_rater1<-c(1,4,3,4,4,2,3,1,3,4)
test4_rater1<-c(1,3,4,2,3,2,1,2,3,2)
test1_rater2<-c(1,3,3,4,3,4,3,2,1,3)
test2_rater2<-c(1,3,1,3,1,3,3,1,1,1)
test3_rater2<-c(1,3,3,2,4,2,3,4,3,4)
test4_rater2<-c(2,3,4,4,3,2,3,2,3,2)
mydata<-data.frame(test1_rater1,test2_rater1,test3_rater1,test4_rater1,test1_rater2,test2_rater2,test3_rater2,test4_rater2)

# For the kappa statistic, I used:

cohen.kappa(cbind(test1_rater1,test1_rater2))
cohen.kappa(cbind(test2_rater1,test2_rater2))
cohen.kappa(cbind(test3_rater1,test3_rater2))
cohen.kappa(cbind(test4_rater1,test4_rater2))
```

As in my data frame is data from over 80 different tests, this solution is quiet complicated... I thougt about a list and then using the lapply function, but i did not work. Is there e shorter way to do this?

Thanks, Nat

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Why did the lapply not work? Please show your code and the expected output.

Comment: maybe a starting point [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32203753/export-fixed-range-of-columns-from-dataframe-to-pdf-one-slice-per-sheet)

Comment: You could `split` the column names and then use `lapply` i.e `lapply(split(names(mydata), sub('_.*', '', names(mydata))), function(x) cohen.kappa(mydata[x]) )`

Answer (score 4):

The first step is to [tidy](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v59/i10/paper) your data: instead of having one column for each pair of test and rater, have a column for `test`, then columns for `rater1` and `rater2`. You can do this restructuring with the dplyr and tidyr packages:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
rearranged_data <- mydata %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  gather(column, value, -row) %>%
  separate(column, c("test", "rater")) %>%
  spread(rater, value)

head(rearranged_data)
#>   row  test rater1 rater2
#> 1   1 test1      1      1
#> 2   1 test2      1      1
#> 3   1 test3      1      1
#> 4   1 test4      1      2
#> 5   2 test1      4      3
#> 6   2 test2      3      3
```

Now you can perform the Cohen-kappa calculation within each test. This will require a function to turn a `kappa` object into a data frame. You could use this function:

```
library(broom)
tidy_kappa <- function(x) {
  broom::fix_data_frame(x$confid, newcol = "type")
}
```

If you install the newest version of my [broom package](https://github.com/dgrtwo/broom) with `devtools::install_github("dgrtwo/broom")`, you could just use the `tidy` method, as I've just added one like this to the package.

Now you can perform your `cohen.kappa` tests with dplyr's `group_by` and `do`:

```r
library(psych)
results <- rearranged_data %>%
  group_by(test) %>%
  do(tidy_kappa(cohen.kappa(cbind(.$rater1, .$rater2))))
results
#> Source: local data frame [8 x 5]
#> Groups: test
#> 
#>    test             type       lower  estimate     upper
#> 1 test1 unweighted kappa  0.08574000 0.4594595 0.8331789
#> 2 test1   weighted kappa  0.07284356 0.5238095 0.9747755
#> 3 test2 unweighted kappa -0.10654813 0.3333333 0.7732148
#> 4 test2   weighted kappa -0.09877879 0.4444444 0.9876677
#> 5 test3 unweighted kappa  0.19876127 0.5833333 0.9679054
#> 6 test3   weighted kappa -0.39241493 0.3577982 1.1080113
#> 7 test4 unweighted kappa  0.21116862 0.5714286 0.9316885
#> 8 test4   weighted kappa -0.02324226 0.4444444 0.9121311
```

This approach will work no matter how many tests you have, resulting in two rows for each (one with unweighted kappa, one with weighted: just like the output of the `cohen.kappa` function). Note that this output format is useful for graphing or further analyzing the results:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(results, aes(estimate, test)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin = lower, xmax = upper)) +
  facet_wrap(~ type) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, color = "red", linetype = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks David. I actually do not know what all the codes mean but finally it worked!